# how to reach message endpoints when using @Bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

when I using the configuration as described in spring docs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class MyFlowConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<String> consoleSource() {
        return CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "httpChannel")
    public ObjectToMapTransformer toMapTransformer() {
        return new ObjectToMapTransformer();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "httpChannel")
    public MessageHandler httpHandler() {
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler("http://foo/service");
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
        handler.setOutputChannelName("outputChannel");
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
    public LoggingHandler loggingHandler() {
        return new LoggingHandler("info");
    }

}
```

What kind of bean definition name I may use to reach the endpoints?
When using configuration via components there is provided information in docs:

> The processing of these annotations creates the same beans (AbstractEndpoints and MessageHandlers (or MessageSources for the inbound channel adapter - see below) as with similar xml components. The bean names are generated with this pattern: [componentName].[methodName].[decapitalizedAnnotationClassShortName] for the AbstractEndpoint and the same name with an additional .handler (.source) suffix for the MessageHandler (MessageSource) bean. The MessageHandlers (MessageSources) are also eligible to be tracked by Section 8.2, “Message History”.

But how it can be used here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to **inject** some of those endpoints to your services. Not sure "why?", but it can be done like this (e.g. for that `httpHandler`):

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("myFlowConfiguration.httpHandler.serviceActivator")
private AbstractEndpoint httpEndpoint;
```

According to the rule described above:

- `myFlowConfiguration` - the bean name of the class which contains the method with `@ServiceActivator`. In your case it is your `@Configuration`
- `httpHandler` the method name with `@ServiceActivator`
- `serviceActivator` - the decapitalized name of the `@ServiceActivator`.

Is that clear ?

**UPDATE**

> I don't use xml context, only java based configuration, so answer is `@Import`

Good, thanks. That is an answer. Any `@Import` `@Configuration` are present with bean names with fully-qualified class name including package (from `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`):

```
/* using fully qualified class names as default bean names */
 private BeanNameGenerator importBeanNameGenerator = new   AnnotationBeanNameGenerator() {
    @Override
    protected String buildDefaultBeanName(BeanDefinition definition) {
        return definition.getBeanClassName();
    }
};
```

So, we have to keep that in mind, if we are going to use reference to endpoint from those `unnamed` class.

Of course, to simplify your life you can just add a `name` to your `MyFlowConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration("myFlowConfiguration")
@EnableIntegration
public class MyFlowConfiguration {
```

Comment: i have tried by the way you wrote about. actually I need use it via control bus (ex. @'myFlowConfiguration.httpHandler.serviceActivator'.start()). So firstly I try to do just context.getBean("myFlowConfiguration.httpHandler.serviceActivator") and got NoSuchBeanDefinition :( so it doesn't work

Comment: Good. Whould you mind to check this in debug `context.getBeansOfType(EventDrivenConsumer.class)` and take a look which bean name has an endpoint for that `httpHandler()` ?

Comment: And? What is the name of your endpoint? We might isn't right in that description. So, it should be fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: it is mapped with package.MyFlowConfiguration.httpHandler.serviceActivator, when use component with @MessageEndpoint annotation it is mapped exactly as wrote in docs and you replied here

Comment: So, do you mean, that `context.getBeansOfType(MyFlowConfiguration.class)` returns single bean for your `MyFlowConfiguration` but its name is with package ?

Comment: Right, that's correct. But I looked to the debug for our https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/web-sockets/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/websocket/standard/server/Application.java and the `splitter()`'s `endpoint` has a name `application.splitter.serviceActivator`. So, it isn't clear to me why yours is with package...

Comment: actually to me too... but I might guess to try such name, because before I have seen that default poller metadata is created with similar long name.

Comment: So, one more time: which bean name has your `MyFlowConfiguration`? How do you use it to create an `ApplicationContext` ?

Comment: I have created application context just as bean that scoped by my custom scope. May hence the different?

Comment: Maybe... Can you confirm that your `MyFlowConfiguration` bean really has bean mane with `package`? Because SI `MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor` just use it as is. After your answer it will be needed to investigate in which cases we have such a behaviour.

Comment: now in my real application I use control bus that works with endpoints via for example `package.MyFlowIntegration.inAdapter.serviceActivator.stop()`... so yes. I confirm this point.

Comment: OK. Anyway. How do you instantiate `MyFlowConfiguration` for the application context? `<bean>` or `@Import` ?

Comment: I don't use xml context, only java based configuration, so answer is `@Import`

Comment: Updated my answer according to your comments.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it is absolutely clear for me :)